# Windows Service Installation

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services

#### Scenario

I have a server, that has NO Visual Studio Installed. It literally has a normal command prompt and nothing installed yet. We don't want to install anything (except the .Net framework which we have already done). We just want to install a bunch of C# Windows Services that we have written.

#### So far

I have been installing and running the windows service on my local machine using a "setup and deploy" project that I built into the application, which I could then use to install the service locally.

#### Question

How can I install the service on the server?
I imagine it can be done from the command prompt only, but what else do I need? - If anything? and where do I put the files that I want to install BEFORE I install them?
I imagine I will have to compile the application on my local machine in Visual Studio, then copy it over to the server, and then run an install utility to install it on the server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check other SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275542/confusion-about-installing-windows-service-using-command-prompts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your server has a `sc.exe` (service control) command which allows you to install, uninstall, start, stop and configure services - no Visual Studio bits needed.

Run  `sc.exe -?` at a command prompt to get a listing of all available options

Answer (score 33):

according to this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d8f300e3-6c09-424f-829e-c5fda34c1bc7http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d8f300e3-6c09-424f-829e-c5fda34c1bc7) you need to run

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe C:\MyService.exe
```

(replace c:\windows with your windows path)

Comment: +1 InstallUtil is part of the runtime install, not the SDK so this is the way to do it!

Comment: Remember to replace the Framework version with the right number!

Answer (score 2):

I add code similar to the one in this article to my services:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WinSvcSelfInstaller.aspx

Then I can install/uninstall them just by typing ServiceName -i or ServiceName -u at the command prompt. Makes it easier if it'll be installed by people who don't know .Net.

Comment: +1 yup, a very neat way of installing/uninstalling your services!

Comment: i realy appreciate it